# generating a python variable using concatenation of two strings

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have an already defined variable,which I want to access using concatenation of two strings to make that variable name.But this treats the later as a string.

```
list1=[]
if len("list"+str(1))==0:
    print "yes"
```

Here the length comes out as 5,as it treats list1 as a string,How can I access my previous list1,if I have to generate the variable name dynamically?

Comment: This is almost always a bad idea; use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Yes, I got the solution using dictionary itself! Thank you -@HughBothwell and @jonrsharpe